# Centralize background images

Tags: css

I am able to put a x1600 width background image in different screen resolution with the following code :) It works perfectly as it centralized in smaller resolution.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
        background: #f8f7e5 url(images/header-top.jpg) no-repeat center top;    
    color: #333333;
}
#content {

    width: 860px;
    margin: 238px auto 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}
<body>

<div id="content">
    <p>details</p>
</div>
```

However, in that large background image, I need to add the effect of changing the menu colour when hover over the menu. With that, i crop that background images into 3 rows ( header, menu, bottom). Under the menu section, i cropped each menu vertically and duplicate the menu with different colour. Then i combine all the cropped images back into a background image.

The hover effect on menu works perfectly, but background image is no longer align center in smaller resolution. It aligned to the right instead :(

Previously it works fine if i put the background picture into the BODY in CSS. However, after the picture is cropped, i am no longer able to put those into the BODY.

This is my code

```
<div class="menu_image"><img src="images/backgrounds/header-background1.jpg" border="0" /></div>     
    <div style="line-height: 0px; width:1600px">
          <div class="menu_image"><img src="images/backgrounds/header-menu1.jpg" /></div>
          <a class="menuhover" href="index.php"/>
          <a class="menuhover2" target="blank" href="http"></a>
          <a class="menuhover3" href="about-us.php"></a>
          <a class="menuhover4" href="portfolio.php"></a>
          <a class="menuhover5" href="contact-us.php"></a>
          <div class="menu_image"><img src="images/backgrounds/header-menu7.jpg" /></div>
    </div>    
     <div class="menu_image"><img src="images/backgrounds/header-background3.jpg" /></div>
```

How do i align the background images above in center in any screen resolution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't create solid background(BG) image for page and for menu use additional background image for menu block, which will be shown on top of big solid image and display your hover effects?

ADDED:

You can use only hover BG image for menu BG change. So you don't need to exclude background of menu zone from main BG.

`OnMouseOver` - load BG for menu, which overwrite default bg of menu zone.

`OnMouseOut` - `none` for menu background, so you see your default page BG.

Comment: This sounds to be a very good idea !! Can you please advise how do i apply the mouse hover effect on each button? So i shall create a background without the menu first. And add the menu manually with <div> and position: absolute on top of that background image. And i can use back the code i pasted on top ?  Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can that happen? Do you use the coordinate to identify the menu location? Can the map has the mouse hover effect?